# Does $span(A^T)$ equals $span(A^T*A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We've been taught that the next equation:

> $A^TAx= A^Tb$ , where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ are given and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is the possible solution, **has at least one solution**.

I couldn't prove it myself. Is this lemma is correct? if so, how can I prove it?

I tried to rely on the property $\ker{(A)}=\ker{(A^T*A)}$ when proving.

Comment: One solution of what? $b$? $x$?

Comment: One inclusion is obvious. Did you try to count their dimensions?

Comment: Yeah I did! found out that if their kernels are equal - $dimA^TA$ = $dimA$ but I couldn't find the justification why their spans are equal too. I'm missing out some obvious part for sure, sorry for that.